# USB Wifi adapter kali

Tags: wifi, драйвер, kali-linux

Прикупил значит специльно для кали ugreen AC650 high-gain. Спросил у bard`а ибо несильно шарю в теме совместимости. Оказалось нужно драйвера поставить, собственно у производителя скачал
так как я с нулевым опытом, полазил и глянул как ставить. Make не помог. Оставляю скрин, в идеале буду крайне благодарен если научите настройке его включая шаги в Virtualbox
[image: драйвер]

Comment: Dkms сборку поищи